# floated divs in 3-a-row grid, middle row with top offset

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

how do i achieve this as per image attached?

[image]

as you can see, i have equal width blocks floated left, but i want the middle row to have a bit of offset compared to the left and right rows.

is it possible just with plain css, flexbox maybe? or do i have to use something like masonry?

i tried applying a top margin to every block in the middle row but this doesnt work:

```
.block {
 background-color:red;
 height:200px;
 width:33.333%;
 border:1px solid black;
 float:left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block:nth-child(3n+2) {
 margin-top:10px;
 background:blue;
 color:white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oaLh13dL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` instead of floats.

```css
.block_wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.block {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.333% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.block:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_wrap">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
  <div class="block">7</div>
  <div class="block">8</div>
</div>
```